# [Auto layout]Attaching UIView to the bottom of its superview while superview's height is changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a superview which is just a subclass of `UIView`, and I have a subview which is a subclass of `UIImageView` that I want to attach to the bottom of the superview.

The height of the subview is fixed, but the height of the superview is subject to change. So basically, I want the subview to always attach to the bottom of the superview while I change the height of the superview programatically.

I'm doing it by Auto layout,

[image]

So superview has left,top,right attached to its superview, and a fixed height(I gonna change it programatically), here's its constraints,

[image]

And the subview has left, bottom, right attached to the superview, and its fixed height, and another constraint that superview's height should equal or greater than the subview's height.

[image]

Finally, when I tap the button at the very bottom, I change the height of the superview. Here's the code,

```
- (IBAction)testButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.dragDownView setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.dragDownView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.dragDownView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.dragDownView.frame), 100)];
}
```

However, it's not doing what I wanted, which is keep the subview attached to the bottom of the superview.

**Before I change the height**:

[image]

**After I change the height**:

[image]

As you can see the height of the superview is changed, however the subview still keeps what it was before.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: 你使用AutoLayout，就不要直接修改Frame

Comment: 把Constraint连到Controller里，然后像我回答的那样更新就行了。

Answer (score 1):

link constraint:
[image]

update view's frame like this:

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 320;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Autolayout Constraint` you should update `Constraint` instead of `Frame`.

Link `Height constraint` of your `Superview` to `IBOutlet` as @mistyhua suggested.

Now when you what to change `Height` of your `Superview` then instead of changing frame of Superview change Height Constraint value.

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 320;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```